# Глагол как часть речи

Tags: морфология

Может ли инфинитив выступать в роли дополнения, обстоятельства, определения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присел отдохнуть - обстоятельство цели, приказал стрелять (другому лицу) - дополнение (объектный инфинитив), мечта уехать, приказ стрелять - несогласованное определение.